# Copy a graph in Excel with VBA to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a button to copy a graph from a different sheet, on to "Sheet 1" and into cell "G4".

So far i have tried the code below, but there always is an error when "pasting" into the desired destination.

What could you recommend? Any help is greatly appriciated.

Sub OBJC()

Worksheets("Tabelle 2").Charts(1).Copy

Worksheets("Tabelle 1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle 1").Range("G4")

End Sub

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're trying to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but it worked for me when I activated the chart first.

```
    Sub OBJC()    
    Worksheets("Tabelle 2").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    Worksheets("Tabelle 1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle 1").Range("G4")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Subscript out of range (Error 9) comes up. So I must be calling the chart by the wrong name.

Comment: @The_mark  It could be a wrong sheet name, check for leading or trailing space

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you very much!